# Embedded Forms with Rails, Mongoid, and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I have a devise model that embeds many for two other models called has_skills and desires_skills. The attr-accessibles are in place but I still get a WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes:  my_skills_attributes, wanted_skills_attributes error message. Below are my models. Thoughts?

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :wanted_skills
  embeds_many :my_skills
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :my_skills, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :wanted_skills, allow_destroy: true

    .........
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,     :remember_me,  :location, :my_skills, :wanted_skills, :name, :sname
```

My Skills model

```
class MySkill
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :user
  field :name

  attr_accessible  :name
end
```

My has skills model

```
class WantedSkill
 include Mongoid::Document
 embedded_in :user
 field :sname
 attr_accessible  :sname
```

end

Lastly my form

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @user do |f| %>

<%= f.fields_for :my_skills do |task| %>
<%= task.label :name %><br />
<%= task.text_field :name %><br />
<%= task.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %>
<% end %>
<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a task", :my_skills %></p>


<%= f.fields_for :wanted_skills do |task| %>
<%= task.label :sname %><br />
<%= task.text_field :sname %><br />
<%= task.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %>
<% end %>
<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a task", :wanted_skills %></p>
  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the nested attributes work, you need to allow `my_skills_attributes` and not `my_skills`. Thats all.

```
attr_accessible :my_skills_attributes
```